# ROW_NUMBER() Set Null to anything beside Min

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle

So I have this basic setup:

```
Declare @temp Table(t1 varchar(1)
                    ,t2 int)

insert into @temp (t1,t2)
Values 
('a','1')
,('a','2')
,('a','3')
,('a','4')
,('a',null)


select t1,t2,ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY T1 ORDER BY t2) 'rnk'
from @temp
```

The problem is, the value that is Null get ranked the highest. What I am trying to do is set the first non zero/null value to the highest rank(lowest number) current output is:

```
t1  t2     rnk
a   NULL    1
a   0       2
a   1       3
a   2       4
a   3       5
```

I want

```
t1  t2   rnk
a   NULL 4/5 --either or
a   0    4/5
a   1    1
a   2    2
a   3    3
```

I know i can do this with subquerys but the problem is to get t2, is a 200 character case statement that i really don't want to copy and paste all over, once to calculate, then one to order by and such. I am seeing a Query to get the values, inside a query to get the rank,inside a query to only pull those ranked 1, which is 3 deep and i don't know like that. *note i know it say oracle and i am sure at least one person will mark me down since this is in SQL server, BUT, the actual code is in oracle, i am just much better in SQL server and its easy to translate unless Oracle has some magic function that makes this easier.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use two keys for the `order by`.  The following is compatible with both SQL Server and Oracle:

```
select t1, t2,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY T1
                         ORDER BY (CASE WHEN t2 IS NOT NULL OR T2 <> 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END),
                                  t2
                        ) as rnk
from @temp;
```

Oracle supports `NULLS LAST`, which makes it easier:  `ORDER BY t2 NULLS LAST`.

Comment: Gordon I want to give you the credit because you lead me to the correct answer, thanks! Oracle and their magic does it again.

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to use the `ISNULL` function to set it to the max value of the type on null values.  So if `t2` is an integer it would be:

```
select t1,t2,ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY T1 ORDER BY ISNULL(t2,2147483647)) 'rnk'
from @temp
```

This would prevent you from having to use `t2` (your big case statement) in your expression more than once.

I believe Oracle uses `NVL` instead of `ISNULL`.

Comment: `coalesce` is supported by both Oracle and SQL Server and can usually replace `nvl` and `isnull`.